# How to specify which interface/ip address for weechat to connect from (bind to)

Tags: networking, weechat

I just added some extra ip's to my dedicated machine that I run weechat on, I was wondering how I can utilize those ip addresses from weechat...

Ive been googling but I have yet to find anything about binding weechat to specific interface or ip address

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple, type /set, then in the new window, type host + enter, and the settings that involve the word host appear, the setting I was looking for was

```
/set irc.server_default.local_hostname <ip_or_reverse_dns_hostname>
```